# Continuous predictor variable to identify responder genes using DESeq2

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2

I have samples from 45 individuals at 2 time points and these individuals were given a specific diet. The BMI of these individuals were recorded at both time points. The responders to the diet are the ones that show decrease in BMI from T1 to T2. I want to use continuous variable (BMI) to identify genes that are predictors of response to diet. I also have other covariates that need to be controlled like age & gender. The metadata table looks like following

[image]

I am not sure the design that I should go for. The one that I think is appropriate is

```r
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=cts,colData=meta,design=~0+Time+Gender+AGE+Time:BMI)
dds <- DESeq(dds,test="LRT", reduced=~Gender+AGE)
res=results(dds, contrast=list("T1.BMI","T2.BMI"))
```

Is this the correct way to go ahead and to identify responder genes to the diet?

All suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you